# Exponential Concentration Inequality for Higher-order moments of Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. copies of  Gaussian random variable $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. It is known that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\Bigl( \Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j \Bigl| >t\Bigr) &\leq 2 \exp( cnt^2)~~\text{and}\\
\mathbb{P}\Bigl( \Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (X_j^2 - \mathbb{E}X_j^2) \Bigl| >t\Bigr) &\leq 2 \exp( cn\min \{t^2, t\}).
\end{align}
These two results follows from the concentration inequality of sub-Gaussian and sub-exponential random variables and the second one is a Bernstein-type inequality. I wonder if there are similar results for the higher moments of Gaussian random variables. Can one have 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\Bigl( \Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (X_j^4 - \mathbb{E}X_j^4) \Bigl| >t\Bigr) \leq 2 \exp( cnt)?
\end{align}
And more generally, for a centered random variable $Y$ satisfying $\mathbb{P}(|Y| > t) \leq 2 \exp(c t^{\alpha})$ for $\alpha > 0$, can we get an exponential inequality for the concentration of $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$? That is, can we have 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\Bigl( \Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (Y_j - \mathbb{E}Y_j) \Bigl| >t\Bigr) \leq 2 \exp( cnt^\beta)
\end{align}
for some $\beta > 0$？

Answer (score 7):

See Theorem 23 in [Section 9.3 of Ryan O'Donnell's book Analysis of Boolean functions](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?p=1472). Even though the theorem there is stated for $\pm 1$ variables, it holds for Gaussians as well (see Chapter 10 of the book for details on that).

For the more general statement, see Exercise 7 in [these lecture notes of Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/).

Comment: Sorry the previous statement of the question is not correct. Now I've made some corrections. And what can we say for more general random variables with some decaying tail behavior？

Comment: Your more general question is addressed in lecture notes of Terry Tao.